Создание юзербота для ВКонтакте
Приветики! Хочу создать юзербота для соц. сети ВКонтакте. Раньше разбирался с библиотекой без проблем, но в связи с последними обновлениями не получается взаимодействовать с любыми из выбранных.
Можете пожалуйста посоветовать доступные библиотеки и предложить ссылку на документацию? Буду очень благодарен!

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Очень мощная библиотека есть, requests называется

Приветики всем! К счастью, сам же и разобрался в своем вопросе и надеюсь помочь кому-то своим объяснением.
Библиотеки для ВКонтакте очень странно себя ведут, начиная с самого подключения программы к аккаунту. Рассмотрим одну и таковых - vk_api. Хорошим решением будет взять свой персональный токен VK Admin на сайте https://vkhost.github.io/
Важно никому не сообщать его, так как вместе с токеном человек получает доступ к вашему аккаунту.
Итак, полученный токен мы вставляем в код:
import vk_api
token="Ваш токен"
api=vk_api.VkApi(token=token)
session=api.get_api()

Готово! Теперь можно смело творить! С документацией можно ознакомиться по ссылке: https://dev.vk.com/ru/method
Напоследок хотелось бы отметить, что в некоторых случаях программа может выдавать ошибку Unknown method passed. Если вы уверены, что код написан правильно и нет ошибок в вызове метода, то рекомендую для начала просто вызвать данный метод без передачи в него каких-либо параметров. Условно, если брать за основу приведенную выше часть кода, то это будет выглядеть так:
print(session.groups.getByld())

В данном случае программа выведет вместо Unknown method passed параметры, которые нужно передать для правильного выполнения метода.
